# How to detect the exact geographic location of a site visitor

Tags: google-maps, google-api

We have a tool on our travel site which should exactly calculate the distance from the visitor location to a given hotel which is known bye longitude and latitude. To achieve this we use google API but this is not accurate, some time the visitor location is about 40/50 km from the real location. According to other coders is not possible to do better. I can't believe that there is no the possibility to detect the exact geographic location of visitor. I have seen there are some other similar question but those are 2/3 year old.
Thank you

Comment: How are you getting the visitor's position now? Is this a mobile site or desktop site?

Comment: It is a responsive site which is available for all devices

Comment: we use google api to detect location now

Comment: Distance Matrix API is used to calculate distance now

Comment: That doesn't detect a user's location

Comment: @geocodezip what api should we use then?

Answer (score 1):

the location of a device can be obtained in two ways, by means of GPS or by means of the approximate location of the IP. The GPS reception can be affected by various factors .. in the cities is of some importance to the Urban Canyonin ie the reflection of the GPS waves on buildings. these factors can lead to an error of several meters and particularly unfavorable circumstances even of some tens of meters .. Another mode of detection is based on the geo-referencing of the IP and on routing that uses the device through wifi networks or data connections in this case the error on the position is normally a few tens of meters ..